# Bootstrap 4 page does not display properly in some mobile resolutions

Tags: android, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I built a webpage based on Bootstrap 4 example.

When trying to display it in responsible design mode : 980 x 1280 from Firefox all is properly display.

But actually in production mode, when i browse the page from a Galaxy Tab 2 i get the side links (in blue color) are overlapping the main content,especially some "OK !" buttons.

Please see the result here :  http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/1.2/sensors/capture.png

The source is available here : http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/1.2/sensors/sensors14.html

Would you please tell me how i could fix this ?

Comment: @TariqJaved has provided the correct answer. Also remember that Bootstrap 4 is still in alpha so you can expect some inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the table with class="table-responsive"

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: When adding <div class="table-responsive"> i indeed no longer get side links overlapping the main content, but all "OK !" buttons have been wiped out : s529471052.onlinehome.fr/1.2/sensors/sensors15.html (issue visible in 980x1280 resolution)

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead? The table's content is too wide for smaller widths.

Comment: The table is responsive and horizontal scroll able

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the grid system properly. 
[Refer this](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">For Sensor Manager section in your case </div>
  <div class="col-4">For the right side menu should help you</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and fast set **overflow:scroll** style in **parent div of table** Like bellow

```
<div style="overflow:scroll">
    <table>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    </table>
</div>
```

Best way to make a "css class" with overflow property and handle it in media queries.